# Bash script to recursively explore directories, keeping 2 most recent subdirectories ending in X?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, directory

I want to automate a very specific function that I perform often using bash. From the parent directory, I would like to explore each subdirectory recursively. Within each subdirectory, if there are directories ending in '.X', I want to keep only the two most recent of those. It's a little difficult to explain, so here is an example:

```
|-- parent
    |-- dir
        |-- file
        |-- dir
            |-- dir.v1.X
            |-- dir.v2.X
            |-- dir.v3.X
    |-- dir
        |-- file
        |-- dir.v1.x
            |-- file
    |-- dir
        |-- dir.v1.X
        |-- dir.v2.X
        |-- dir.v3.X
        |-- dir.v4.x
        |-- dir.v5.x
```

becomes

```
|-- parent
    |-- dir
        |-- file
        |-- dir
            |-- dir.v2.X
            |-- dir.v3.X
    |-- dir
        |-- file
        |-- dir.v1.x
            |-- file
    |-- dir
        |-- dir.v4.x
        |-- dir.v5.x
```

Comment: please define "most recent"

Comment: Please show your attempt how to solve this, what have you tried and where did it failed.

Comment: so if there are files inside `dir.v4.x` and `dir.v5.x` they should be included in the output? and what if there is 
`dir.v5.x/dir.v6.x/somefile`? what would the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
find your_root_dir -type d -name "*.X" |
  LANG=C sort -r | {
    refdir=
    count=0
    while read dir; do
      dirpart=`dirname $dir`
      if [ "$dirpart" = "$refdir" ]; then
        count=$((count+1)) # or count=`expr $count + 1` in some shells
        if [ $count -gt 2 ]; then
          echo rm -r "$dir" # remove the echo" after testing
        fi
      else
        refdir="$dirpart"
        count=1
      fi
    done
    }
```

it finds directories ending in .X, reverse sorts them so that the ones to be removed are after the ones to be kept, and the subdirs of the same directory are kept together. Then a loop removes the subdirs after the second one.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from the question what "two most recent" means.

If we assume it means the two whose names sort last alphabetically, then:

```bash
find parent -type d -exec bash -c '
        printf "check: [%s]\n" "$@"
        shopt -s nullglob
        for d; do
            x=("$d"/*.X/)
            if (( ( n=${#x[@]} ) > 2 )); then
                printf "keep: [%s]\n" "${x[@]:n-2}"
                printf "delete: [%s]\n" "${x[@]:0:n-2}"
                # rm -r -- "${x[@]:0:n-2}"
            else
                printf "ignore: [%s]\n" "$d"
            fi
        done
    ' -- {} +
```

`find` walks the directory tree rooted at `parent`, looking for directories. It invokes bash on each batch found:

- `shopt -s nullglob` - make globs return empty string when no match
- `x=("$d"/*.X/)` - make a sorted list of all paths with the appropriate name (globbing sorts matches alphabetically) and store in array `x`; trailing `/` ensures only directories are selected
- `${#x[@]}` - number of candidates found
- `n=${#x[@]}` - assign to variable for later use
- `if ((n>2))` - do nothing unless at least three directories were found
- `${x[@]:n-2}"` - the "two most recent" subdirectories
- `"${x[@]:0:n-2}"` - all except the two most recent
- `printf ...` - debugging commands - uncomment the `rm` command if the test output shows desired behaviour

Comment: note that the "ignore" printf will include some directories that would be deleted. Also, some directories will be passed into bash that may get deleted before they get processed but this is fine as the glob will just return empty string

Answer (score 0):

I have this directory structure:

```
$ find . | sort
.
./parent
./parent/dir1
./parent/dir1/dir
./parent/dir1/dir/dir.v1.X
./parent/dir1/dir/dir.v2.X
./parent/dir1/dir/dir.v3.X
./parent/dir1/file
./parent/dir2
./parent/dir2/dir.v1.X
./parent/dir2/dir.v1.X/file
./parent/dir2/file
./parent/dir3
./parent/dir3/dir.v1.X
./parent/dir3/dir.v2.X
./parent/dir3/dir.v3.X
./parent/dir3/dir.v4.X
./parent/dir3/dir.v5.X
```

At the [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr) REPL:

```
$ txr
This is the TXR Lisp interactive listener of TXR 288.
Quit with :quit or Ctrl-D on an empty line. Ctrl-X ? for cheatsheet.
TXR kind of supports IEEE 754.00000000000003 floating-point.
1> (flow (build (ftw "." (lambda (path type . rest)
                           (if (and (eql ftw-d type)
                                    (ends-with ".X" path))
                             (add path)))))
     (group-by dir-name)
     (dohash (dir names @1)
       (each ((n (butlast (sort names) 2)))
         (put-line `delete @n`))))
delete ./parent/dir1/dir/dir.v1.X
delete ./parent/dir3/dir.v1.X
delete ./parent/dir3/dir.v2.X
delete ./parent/dir3/dir.v3.X
nil
```

We have the skeleton of the solution. It's only printing instead of actually deleting. To actually remove those directories recursively, we can use `(remove-path-rec n)` in placeq of the `` (put-line `delete @n`) ``.

If the lexicographic sort isn't good enough, we could implement a version sort. One way to do that is to just break each path into tokens, where the decimal numbers become actual integers, e.g.:

```
3> (defun version-vec (str)
     (flow str
       (tok #/([0-9]+|\w+|(\W|[^0-9])+)/)
       (mapcar [iffi [chain first chr-isdigit] int-str])))
version-vec
4> (version-vec "abc.1234-456.f-y.X")
("abc" "." 1234 "-" 456 "." "f" "-" "y" "." "X")
```

We can use these directly as sorting comparison keys in the `sort` call. Without it, we get the lexicographic order:

```
5> (sort '#"a-13-b a-2-b a-22-b a-9-b a-12-b a-1-b")
("a-1-b" "a-12-b" "a-13-b" "a-2-b" "a-22-b" "a-9-b")
```

1 is followed by 12, 13 and then 2: not necessarily what we want. With `version-vec` as the key function on which items are sorted, this is corrected:

```
6> [sort '#"a-13-b a-2-b a-22-b a-9-b a-12-b a-1-b" : version-vec]
("a-1-b" "a-2-b" "a-9-b" "a-12-b" "a-13-b" "a-22-b")
```

Or, if we wanted to sort some path names by modification time we could use this technique:

```
7> (flow "parent/dir1/dir/*.X"
     glob
     (mapcar stat)
     (sort @1 : .mtime)
     (mapcar .path))
("parent/dir1/dir/dir.v2.X" "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v3.X" "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v1.X")
```

The directories had been created in the `v1`, `v2`, `v3` order. Suppose we touch the timestamp of the `v1` one:

```
8> (touch "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v1.X")
t
9> (flow "parent/dir1/dir/*.X"
     glob                 ;; glob the pattern to get list of names
     (mapcar stat)        ;; map names to list of #(stat ...) structures
     (sort @1 : .mtime)   ;; sort structures by .mtime
     (mapcar .path))      ;; map structures to their paths again
("parent/dir1/dir/dir.v1.X" "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v2.X" "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v3.X")
10> (touch "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v1.X")
t
11> (flow "parent/dir1/dir/*.X"
      glob
      (mapcar stat)
      (sort @1 : .mtime)
      (mapcar .path))
("parent/dir1/dir/dir.v2.X" "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v3.X" "parent/dir1/dir/dir.v1.X")
```

Now `dir1.v1.X` comes last.